# 3D model rendering in android with interactivity

Tags: android, kotlin, 3d, viewer

Hi I’m new to android programming and can make simple apps using Kotlin. I have been tasked to add a 3D object viewer in an android app which will allow the user to interact with the different 3D objects in the view. The interaction should be such that it can have call backs to other activities.

How to I proceed with this? Which 3D object formats can support this. I’d also potentially want multiple 3D models in the same model file. 
I’d also like the 3D models to be coming from a remote internet location.

Any pointers and libraries or frameworks that help with this would be helpful. I’m trying for something likely simpler than OpenGL as it’s just going to be a viewer with simple interactions.

The target device is minimum Android api level 24 so can’t use ARCore or sceneform afaik.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as asking for tutorials or libraries is off-topic. As a start have you even looked an any open source projects which are 3D object viewers for Android?